GitHub issues while pushing
git push origin main
The authenticity of host 'github.com (20.207.73.82)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU.
This key is not known by any other names.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? y
Please type 'yes', 'no' or the fingerprint: yes

Warning: Permanently added 'github.com' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
Connection reset by 20.207.73.82 port 22
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

I did this and when i again tried to push the folder into the repository
git push origin main
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

I couldn't push and actually I'm not sure about SHA and stuff

Is it your repo?
